# Remove poor review audits from the system?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I am not sure where or how to post this but I just was presented with a review question which I personally found rather poor.

[It was listed in the First Posts Review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/12214147) and it looked kind of "spammy" to me, more likely to be promotion for the blog post rather than a real question. Especially because it was listed as a "First Post".

So I tried to comment it with "Is this a question or are you promoting your blog post?" and then the review system hit me.

I mean, those hits don´t hurt, they are a friendly reminder to be concentrated when reviewing but I think the audit questions should be of high quality nevertheless.

I think of the auditing system also as a kind of education to get a feeling for what is appropriate on SO and what not, but this question does not work for that, for me at least.

Is there any way to suggest to remove this question from the audit or do I just have a wrong view on this?

Comment: FWIW you can [use your own votes to fight the garbage audits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773) so that these don't confuse next reviewers

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped!